# In QTP, why are Browser, Page, Frame, and some function calls checkpointed when I have not included checkpoints for them?

Tags: qtp, checkpoint

I have noticed in the Run Results Viewer that my Browser, Page, and Frame objects, as well as some functions, have a "PASSED" status in the report, even though I have not specified that they have checkpoints. After looking in the Run Results Viewer User Guide, it stated that "PASS" or "FAIL" will only be given to objects with checkpoints, so I am stymied. Why is this so, and how can I turn them off? Finally, if I add my own checkpoint with these objects, will it create a conflict?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the report in question?

Comment: And can you add the script that generated that report, please?

Comment: Sorry, but this script is on a classified system, so I cannot download it nor provide a screenshot. I know that makes it more difficult to debug, but I thought someone might have an 'off the top of your head' idea.